# Java preemptive authenticated webservice consumption using CXF

Tags: web-services, authentication, cxf, soapui

I would like to consume a webservice which is secured using CXF. (http://host:port/test/ws?wsdl). Below is my code. but it is giving the exception given below.  In SoapUI i have tested the webservice. I have given credentials in SoapUI under "aut" tab. It was working.
Could you please tell how to consume secured webservice using CXF?

```
ProcessService proxy = new ProcessService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);       
try {       
  IProcessService port = proxy.getBinding1IProcessService();
  Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
  HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
  http.getAuthorization().setUserName("username");
  http.getAuthorization().setPassword("password");


  System.out.println("Result=" + port.startReturnDDCStatusForAC(""));
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception:

```
 Okt 09, 2012 7:23:50 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
    INFO: Creating Service {http://tempuri.org/}ProcessService from WSDL: http://sn000333.tauri.ch:61527/WS/Process?wsdl
    Okt 09, 2012 7:24:02 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
    WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http}BasicAuthentication registered.
    org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.chooseAlternative(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:165)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.finalizeConfig(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:145)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.initialize(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:141)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.createEndpointPolicyInfo(PolicyEngineImpl.java:549)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:295)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:278)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyDataEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyDataEngineImpl.java:61)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.updateClientPolicy(HTTPConduit.java:318)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.<init>(HTTPConduit.java:303)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getConduit(HTTPTransportFactory.java:250)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:235)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:103)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.selectConduit(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:77)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.getConduit(ClientImpl.java:842)
        at com.test.TestWS.main(TestWS.java:66)
```

SOAPUI test:

Under aut tab , i have given below deatils and it is working. 
Authorisation type: preemptive
username: username
password: password

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to make your own **MyBasicAuthSupplier** by extending **HttpBasicAuthSupplier** and overriding **getPreemptiveUserPass**. Then you can set instance of new class to **HTTPConduit** using **setAuthSupplier** method.

This will probably be more useful.

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/apache-cxf/rt/transports/http/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/HTTPConduitTest.java.shtml

Cheers.